# Quickly locate an IP address within 3 million rows of CIDR formatted IP ranges

Tags: python, ip-address, cidr

I have obtained the IP-based geolocation database, which is of the following format:

```
1.0.0.0/24,2077456,2077456,,0,0,,-33.4940,143.2104,1000
1.0.1.0/24,1814991,1814991,,0,0,,34.7725,113.7266,50
1.0.2.0/23,1814991,1814991,,0,0,,34.7725,113.7266,50
1.0.4.0/22,2077456,2077456,,0,0,,-33.4940,143.2104,1000
1.0.8.0/21,1814991,1814991,,0,0,,34.7725,113.7266,50
...
223.255.254.0/24,1880252,1880251,,0,0,37,1.3267,103.8869,5
223.255.255.0/24,2077456,2077456,,0,0,,-33.4940,143.2104,1000
```

There are totally over 3 million rows contained in a CSV file. The first section of each line is CIDR formatted IP range.

I need an efficient way to quickly locate a given IP address among these lines. For example, given the IP address `1.0.1.2`, I want to quickly locate the second line, so I can then obtain its coordination, which are the rest of data in this row. I wonder if there is any efficient way to do this, instead of inspection each row from the beginning.

The difficulty lies in, for example, the IP range `1.0.2.0/23` includes the IP address `1.0.3.0`, so mere string matching will not work very well.

Comment: is the ip always at the start?

Comment: Yes it is, it is actually from GeoLite2 IP-based geolocation database, each line is the same format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way myself. First to convert the 8-bit sectioned IP address into decimal format, which makes the CIDR formatted IP range into two decimal numbers. Then I used the `bisect` module to find the range where the IP belongs to.

Answer (score -1):

```
def search_line(csv, ip):
    for line in csv:
        if line.startswith(ip):
            return line
```

Comment: I don't think `startswith` will help with matching IP addresses to CIDR ranges.

Comment: Thanks, but I need to do calculation here, merely string matching will not work.

Comment: Maybe I missunderstood your question then, but didn't u want the line where the ip occured? Why is string matching not gona work? You can then split the line into a list like: line.split(",") and get the last part for example like this: line.split(",")[-1]

Comment: Because for CDIR formatted IP, ```1.0.2.0/23``` will include ```1.0.3.0```, so merely string matching will not work.